# DPD Predict service fields via Postmen label API

Tags: api, label, predict, dpd

We're using Postmen to create shipping labels ( https://docs.postmen.com/dpd-uk.html#labels-create-a-label ) which all works perfectly fine, but the courier used is DPD who have a Predict service that basically sends out sms/email notifications to the customer regarding estimated delivery times etc.

When creating labels manually via the DPD portal, in addition to the delivery/contact fields, there are two extra fields labelled "Notification Email" and "Notification Text", i.e. an email address field and mobile phone number field.

I expected that populating the email and phone fields of the ship_to portion of the shipment array would be enough for these fields to self populate, but it seems this isn't the case. I can't seem to find any other fields in Postmen's documentation though, regarding additional phone/email data or the Predict service itself.

Does anybody know if DPD's API and Postmen support population of these fields? Or perhaps this only works with specific service_type and address type combinations? Links to the relevant sections within the documentation would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and since August 5 we support those fields, we populate the required fields in the following way,

- Notification Email - [ship_to.email](https://docs.postmen.com/#address)
- Notification Text - [ship_to.phone](https://docs.postmen.com/#address)

Unfortunately we don't provide documentation about specific couriers mappings right now.

Source:  I'm a developer from Postmen.

Comment: @zvone Don't understand how this doesn't provide an answer. His question is: `Does anybody know if DPD's API and Postmen support population of these fields?`. The answer:  `we populate them with the ship_to.email and ship_to.phone information`, what needs clarification?